# Disable select if only one option available

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey so I have this HTML (outputted via PHP loop):

```
<select class="dropdown" id="pa_genre" name="attribute_pa_genre">
    <optgroup label="Choose an option:"></optgroup>
    <option value="sport" selected="selected">Sport</option>
</select>
```

And this jQuery (taken from [Disable a <select /> if there is only one <option /> with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002360/disable-a-select-if-there-is-only-one-option-with-jquery)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $sca = $("select.dropdown");
    if ($sca.find("option").length <= 1) {
        $sca.prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

But can't get it to work.. I do have more than one dropdown on the page with the same class (hence why targeting the class not id). I changed the `attr` to `prop` because I'm sure it's the new version and `attr` isn't used anymore..

Comment: Looks like it's working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BTpB9/)

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker yeah but I'll have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BTpB9/2/

Comment: I think the logic might be flawed a little bit, if you have 2 select.dropdown elements on the page, that both have 1 option each, then the result of $sca.find('option') will be 2, i.e. neither will be disabled. I would use an each on the initial selector, to process each one at a time

Comment: @OJay well that makes sense to why I couldn't figure out why no errors were coming up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have more than one input, you need some form of iteration to set their `disabled` properties accordingly.

```
$("select.dropdown").prop('disabled', function() {
    return $('option', this).length < 2;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8qQK4/1/)

The above has the same effect as:

```
$("select.dropdown").each(function() {
    this.disabled = $('option', this).length < 2;
});
```

---

Both of the snippets above will automatically set `disabled` to `false` when the select has 2 or more options. If that makes a meaningful difference, you can use this snippet to disable selects with < 2 options without automatically re-enabling selects with >= 2 options:

```
$("select.dropdown").each(function() {
    if ( $('option', this).length < 2 ) this.disabled = true;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8qQK4/2/)

Comment: No problem, updated with simpler equivalents that are easier to understand as well. `:P`